# I got duplicates picture in List on my android application

Tags: android

I've made an Android Application that I can register my itens there.
In this List I have a ImageView,

> Note: I'm using a custom list. I've made 3 class and 2 xmls, where I could custom a list and bind to my main activity .

My problem is when I open tha application the last picture shows on the first item instead of the first picture.

The application should work like this :

[image]

But, it's working like this :

[image]

You can look at loading of application that it takes the correct picture, but when tha application is loaded, it replaces the first picture to the last.

> Note: If click on any itens take me to other activity where I can edit the item, there I see that the picture is right, the problem is in the load .

The class below is where I make the download of the picture.

```
public  class BaixarImagens extends AsyncTask<ImageView, String, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;
    Bitmap img = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        img = download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
        return  img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    public Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
        try
        {
            URL url2 = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
            InputStream input = conexao.getInputStream();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("Erro", ex.toString());
        }
        return  img;
    }
}
```

Here's the method in other class where I inflate an XML FILE (MY CUSTOM LIST),

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  Visualizacao item;
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista,null);
        item = new Visualizacao();
        item.data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtData);
        item.descricao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        item.titulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
        item.foto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtfoto);
        convertView.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (Visualizacao) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //I set a tag, where contains the URL of the picture
    item.foto.setTag(listedNotices.get(position).getFotoUrl());
    //And a I call execute method where I pass a ImageView
    new BaixarImagens().execute(item.foto);

    item.titulo.setText(listedNotices.get(position).getTitulo());
    item.descricao.setText(listedNotices.get(position).getDescricao());
    item.data.setText(listedNotices.get(position).getData());

    return convertView;
}
```

Ok guys,  If you did not understand, please write down, but help me.

Here's the method where I can get all registers from my database.

```
 private ArrayList<Noticia> getListData() { //return an list of noticia, noticia is an object

  ArrayList<Noticia> results = new ArrayList<Noticia>();

 try {
 BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM cadastroUser;"; //getting data from the DB
 Cursor cursor = BancoDados.rawQuery(sql, null);//

 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     do {

         results.add(new Noticia(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("titulo")),
                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("descricao")),
                 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("foto")),cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))));


     } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
        BancoDados.close();

       }


    }catch(Exception ex){

    mensagemAlert("Erro: " , ex.toString());

    }

    return results;
```

}

and Here's the method where I bind the datas with my listview.

```
   public void carregar(){

        ArrayList<Noticia> items = getListData(); // I bind the data that I        got with this array.


        final ListView listaTela = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listacostomizada); //Here I get a ListView , and I setAdpter passing this elements.
        listaTela.setAdapter(new LisaCustomized(this, items));






}
```

Comment: Do you have any code from where you fill the entire list? Apparently the second part only shows the code of each item individually.

Comment: Ok , I've posted the rest of my code.